# Python regex sub with 1 following paramter

Tags: python, regex

How would I change....

```
"Take dog1 and dog5 to the dog kennel"
```

to

```
"Take animal_1 and animal_5 to the dog kennel"
```

?  So I only want to substitute "animal_" for "dog" if "dog" has a number after it.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Did you try doing some research? The simplest way would be to match the digit and put it back in the replacement. Another way would be to use a lookahead.

Comment: I've read the python doc on regex, the tutorialspoint doc as well as these message boards.  I've been playing around with my interpreter with no luck.  I could do it with ordinary python but I figured there would be a short way with regex.

Comment: I gave you two hints with that comment. Did you make use of them? The lookahead itself takes a while to be understood usually.

Comment: I got my answer from a quick read of the python regex functions.  But mine below is also the most basic.

Comment: @Jerry I said thats how I found my solution (answered below).  I think you mean the guy who asked the question (user3319934)

Comment: @user2615862 Sorry about that. Too many `user\d+` here lol. Will fix that =P

Comment: @user3319934 You really couldn't find it in the end on your own? It's right there on the [python documentation page in the last line of the first paragraph](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below `re.sub` function,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Take dog1 and dog5 to the dog kennel"
>>> m = re.sub(r'dog(\d)', r'animal_\1', s)
>>> m
'Take animal_1 and animal_5 to the dog kennel'
```

Through lookahead,

```
>>> m = re.sub(r'dog(?=\d)', r'animal_', s)
>>> m
'Take animal_1 and animal_5 to the dog kennel'
```

Comment: Ah!  This is what I was looking for.  It works.  I couldn't find out how to reference the parameter.  "\1" did the trick.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm a noob here.

Answer (score 1):

you can probably do the following:

```
import re

old_sting = 'Take dog1 and dog5 to the dog kennel'

dog_finder = re.compile(r'dog(\d+)')
new_string = re.sub(dog_finder, lambda dog: 'animal_' + dog.group(1), old_sting)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> def dog_replace(matchobj):
...     number = matchobj.group(0)[-1:];
...     return "animal_"+ number
>>> re.sub('dog[0-9]', dog_replace, "Take dog1 and dog5 to the dog kennel")
"Take animal_1 and animal_5 to the dog kennel"
```

This works as I have tested it on my local machine.  It is essentially the same as the lambda...i'm just an old bear and I think this is more readable.